# Autosize object in a form

Tags: vb.net

How can I make an autosize form include all the objects in a form designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that the controls inside the form should autosize when the form resizes?
Just set the `Anchor` property of the controls, if you set it to anchor to all 4 sides, they'll resize exactly like the form they're in.

If you need to do anything more advanced you can handle the forms resizing event and write code in there to resize other things at the same time.